# Can't play video in Android Lollipop

Tags: video, java, android, android-studio

I am trying to reproduce a video in android this code doesn’t work for Android Lollipop help please I tried this:

```
        String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.video/"+R.raw.a;
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(videopath);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                             videoView.start();    
            }
        });
```

This is the error:

```
03-02 23:09:50.923 8141-8158/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-02 23:09:50.923 8141-8157/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-02 23:09:50.936 8141-8141/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
03-02 23:09:50.936 8141-8141/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
03-02 23:09:50.967 8141-8141/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
03-02 23:09:50.967 8141-8141/com.example.video D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
03-02 23:09:50.977 8141-8141/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
03-02 23:09:50.978 8141-8141/com.example.video D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
03-02 23:09:50.987 8141-8141/com.example.video E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
03-02 23:09:50.987 8141-8141/com.example.video D/VideoView: Error: -38,0
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it the problem was the video format with lollipop and old versions i to re-encode the video with the baseline H.264 profile using a tool like Handbrake.

Comment: Hi! can you share me which H.264 profile did you use?